# Applications of BSTs in HPC

Tags: binary-search-tree, hpc

Are Binary Search Trees used in HPC workloads?

I know that `quad-trees` and `oct-trees` are used to represent 2D and 3D spaces in many HPC applications. For example `Barnes-Hut algorithm` uses `oct-trees`. `Quad-trees` are used in `CFD` applications. But I'm not able to find any workload which uses a `BST` or a parallel/concurrent version of `BST`

Comment: I feel like you've answered your question in the statement. In what sense is a partitioning k-d tree not a binary search tree?

Comment: quad-trees and oct-trees are extensions of BST in 2D and 3D. But I'm looking for applications of 1D BST. I understand that many HPC workloads have 2D or 3D space, so it is hard to find an application for 1D BST

Comment: the purpose of this question is, I have a concurrent version of BST and I would like to replace a BST in a practical HPC workload with this concurrent version and see if I get a boost in performance

Answer (score 1):

> Are Binary Search Trees used in HPC workloads?

Yes they are, as just many other basic data structures.

BST are just special variant of graphs, so they can be parallelized. Most complex part is rebalancing the tree when there are lot of changes to it (unbalanced BST is still BST) and the number of processors is high. Not all clusters are equally good for graph tasks, and [PGAS environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitioned_global_address_space) may be better.

For example, some parallel implementations of BST and some BST used in HPC libraries:

- [A Parallelized Binary Search Tree (2011)](http://www.omicsgroup.org/journals/a-parallelized-binary-search-tree-2165-7866.1000103.pdf) - PTTRNFNDR - for searching patterns in DNA sequences; threading parallelism is shown
- [Parallel construction of multidimensional binary search trees](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/71.841750), 2000 shows that k-d trees, which are Multidimensional binary search tree, were useful for spatial data
- Parallel BST are implemented in [the Cactus scientific framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_Framework), cactuscode.org - [Implementation of a Binary Tree Driver (OAKc) in Cactus](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~gallen/Students/Jeff_Paper_NCUR06.pdf): "*Many different applications use binary tree structures for the efficiency they provide; including high performance databases, visualization hierarchies, discrete mathematics, MonteCarlo simulations, logic programming and computational econometrics*"
- There is BST in TMVA4, part of [ROOT library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROOT), used in CERN: http://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/TMVA__BinarySearchTree.html - 4.2 of http://tmva.sourceforge.net/docu/TMVAUsersGuide.pdf
- HDF5 format library uses BST internally for "*indexing...chunks on disk*": https://webgrn0001.llnl.gov/prepress/WECOBA07.PDF